# Multiple divs side by side with percentage and fixed width inline

Tags: css, html

I have a parent div with 100% width. How can I put a div on each side of the parent div with a width of 40px so I have 3 divs inline and the parent div has the whole viewport width - (2 * 40px).

What ever I do like float:left on all 3 or on each side I use a span and the parent div has display:inline-block (to consider the width:100% but do not linebreak) I can not make it work correctly.

I need to be compatible to IE8+ and latest FF/Chrome/Safari

Thats my code sample: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/IGsoe

```
<div id="navBar">
    <div>
      <div style="height:100%;width:100%;background:lightgray;padding:5px;">
        <div data-bind="text: number"></div>        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style="height:100%;width:100%;width:100%;background:lightgray;padding:5px;">
        <div data-bind="text: number"></div> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style="height:100%;width:100%;background:lightgray;padding:5px;">
        <div data-bind="text: number"></div> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style="height:100%;width:100%;background:lightgray;padding:5px;">
        <div data-bind="text: number"></div> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style="height:100%;width:100%;background:lightgray;padding:5px;">
        <div data-bind="text: number"></div> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>


:html, body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  font-family:arial;
}

*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

#navBar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;     
}


#navBar > div {
    text-align:left;
    font-size:20px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #000;
    border-style: solid;    
    float:left;
    margin-left:
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with float, the classic is the floats first (right/left) , then middle in the flux with overflow:hidden; http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iGvHd

Else , you have display:table; wich is more coherent and solid. It's understood by IE8.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sBcjp

Comment: I guess the reason why you float:right the very right div is because the middle div with width:100% forces a div with float:left to line-break? but the float:right div is forced to the right. Is that assumption correct? Yeah IE8 seem to have some float bugz...

Comment: @Pascal , yes, before to float, the element is suppose to line-break  if element before it is in the flow. IE always had some strange behavior in the past :)

Comment: When the left/right div has a width of 40px why do I see only this width when I put text inside those divs?

Comment: because it is set at 40px, you may increase width or not give any

Comment: ah i must have been blind. I removed left again and the width stays ??? Dont ask me now what I did before LOL... Thanks again.